# How to create S3 bucket in AWS lambda function using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a S3 bucket and upload some data into S3 buckets. But I have few questions about AWS Lambda service.

1. How to create, delete, upload s3 bucket using AWS Lambda function (Java)?
2. I am using React native as a front-end so I have to call a lambda API call to create the s3 bucket or doing something in the backend. And my question is, can I use different languages in both sides? (i.e React is my front end and Java is my backend).

Comment: What code have you tried? This is a site for asking programming questions, not for asking somebody else to write the code for you. For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Note also that while creating a bucket is technically possible (and straightforward) in this context, the fact that you want to do this as described seems to imply a misunderstanding about when and why buckets should be created.  A bucket is a top level container, and generally a long-lived entity, and [*"it is not appropriate to create or delete buckets on the high-availability code path of your application. It is better to create or delete buckets in a separate initialization or setup routine that you run less often."*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html)

Answer (score 0):

1-You can create/delete/upload by S3 client for Java, for more info check the AWS SDK for Java 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html

2-Yes, you can write your Lambda function in one of the languages AWS Lambda supports.

- NodeJs
- Java
- Go
- C#
- Python

For more info read the following doc
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/programming-model.html